# ReCreate Readable Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array look like this via CSV:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Agent Name
            [1] => Total Calls
            [2] => Customer Services 
            [3] => Voicemail 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paul
            [1] => 53
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sarah
            [1] => 51
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
        )
)
```

I would like to tidy an array to make it to more readable and easy to use.

I want an array to look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Paul] => Array
        (
            [Agent Name] => Paul
            [Total Calls] => 53
            [Customer Services ] => 30
            [Voicemail ] => 0
        )

    [Sarah] => Array
        (
            [Agent Name] => Sarah
            [Total Calls] => 51
            [Customer Services ] => 0
            [Voicemail ] => 0
        )

)
```

I have came up with this solution and it work:

```
$fields = $report[0];
array_shift($report);

$data = array();

foreach($report as $row) {
      $data[$row[0]] = array();
      foreach($row as $k => $val) {
        $data[$row[0]][$fields[$k]] = $val;
      }
}

return $data;
```

Is there a better shorter way doing this?

Comment: Define what you mean by *better*. Do you mean more efficient? Do you mean more readable? Do you mean something else?

Comment: @crush The php code I have just done, is there alternative to way to make it shorter and possibly readable.

Comment: Common, you've got like a 5 line solution there, and you want "better". **Why**? Regardless, off-topic for Stack Overflow. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can combine your first two lines into a single one: `$fields = array_shift($report);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result =array();
for($i=1;$i<count($arr);$i++){
   $result[$arr[$i][0]] = array_combine(array_values($arr[0]),$arr[$i]);
 }
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/98667)

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps do it like this:

```
$f = array_shift($report);

$a = array_combine(array_column($t = array_map(function ($r) use ($f)
{
  return array_combine($f, $r);
}
, $report), 'Agent Name'), $t);
```